# R - Microsoft Access mdb database in Windows

Tags: database, r, odbc

i have followed these steps to install Access Database Engine, configure the ODBC data source and create a user DSN abc linked to abc.mdb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing and [How to read data from Microsoft Access .accdb database files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109844/how-to-read-data-from-microsoft-access-accdb-database-files-into-r)

No issues.

However, odbcConnect("abc") is giving me this error: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is with regards to 32bit v 64 bit i think. Is your R 32 bit or 64 bit. It is likely you created a 32 bit DSN. `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` will create a 64 bit version. By default control panel points to `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe` which would be the 32bit version

Comment: my R is 64 bit and i have already changed to c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

Comment: im using 64 bit Access, 64 bit Access Database Engine and 64 bit R

Comment: Strangely enough, now i am running under C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe and everything is fine with 64 bit R while SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe only works for the 32 bit version.

Comment: WOW64 is for the 32-bit version on 64-bit, the System32/ ones are for the native architecture, it's easy to remember once you realize how hard it is to remember

Comment: Just to add on, i had to re-install MS Access to 64 bit version and then installed MS Access Database Engine for 64 bit version.