# Query MS Access DB from R with 64-bit Windows

Tags: r, ms-access-2010, rodbc

Someone asked me to create a Shiny UI to allow them to read and write from their Microsoft Access database, created with MS Office 2010.

I was following [this](http://rprogramming.net/connect-to-ms-access-in-r/) guide to connect to the Access DB with `RODBC` and -- while I can open this database in Access itself -- I get the following error from R:

```
> channel <- odbcConnectAccess("AD_Users.accdb")
Error in odbcConnectAccess("AD_Users.accdb") : `
  odbcConnectAccess is only usable with 32-bit Windows
```

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window) solution and gave it a try:

```
> channel <- odbcDriverConnect("AD_Users.accdb")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("AD_Users.accdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("AD_Users.accdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute
3: In odbcDriverConnect("AD_Users.accdb") : ODBC connection failed
> channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=AD_Users.accdb")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=AD_Users.accdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=AD_Users.accdb") :
  ODBC connection failed
>
```

but as you can see, there were some pretty serious warnings. It doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other work-around?

I am using 32-bit R when I receive these warnings and even though they're warnings and not technically errors, the database connection is unsuccessful.

***Update***

This seems to establish a successful connection, though I've been unable to query data from it thusfar:

```
channel <- odbcConnectDbase("AD_Users.accdb")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `odbcConnectAccess2007` in `RODBC` and don't have any issues connecting to Access databases when using 64-bit windows.  However, you should check the package manual ([link to pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf)) to make sure that you have the appropriate drivers installed on your computer.  Once you have the right drivers you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that function to be of use since it's 2010 instead of 2007, but it did work.