# Merge data from several MS Access databases

Tags: r, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to merge data from several tables in several MS Access databases.  All the tables have the same structure.  I found this script online and, visually, it seems to do exactly what I want it to do.

```
Parent.Folder <- "D:/Documents/Rwd"
subfolders <- list.dirs(Parent.Folder, recursive = TRUE)[-1]

list_filenames <- list.files(subfolders, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
acc_files <- list_filenames[grep(".mdb|.accdb", list_filenames)]

output <- lapply(acc_files, 
                 function(file) {
                    channel <- odbcConnectAccess(file) 
                    # ALTERNATIVE CONNECTION
                    # channel <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0('driver=
                    #            {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                    #            DBQ=', file))                        
                    data <- sqlQuery(channel, "select * from HRESULTS")
                    close(channel)
                    return(data) 
                })

data <- do.call(rbind, output)
```

The thing is, it gives me an error.

```
Error in odbcConnectAccess(file) : 
  odbcConnectAccess is only usable with 32-bit Windows
```

I started R in 32-bit mode and it throws the error described above.

Any idea what could be wrong? I googled it, and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this process, but the error reads (to me) as you need to be using a 32 bit version of windows OS. See the following [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window).

Comment: Yes!  Right!  I have Windows 7, 64-bit.  But, how do I get around this issue?  I can't switch to a different machine.  There must be some kind of work-around.

Comment: Read the post and try the stuff there that are 64 bit related.

Comment: Try using `odbcConnectAccess2007()` instead of `odbcConnectAccess()`.

Comment: Thanks Gord.  That's a great suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  Now, I get this:


Error in sqlQuery(channel, "select * from Products") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed