# Executing R script from command button in Microsoft Access and passing data from Microsoft Access to R

Tags: sql-server, r, ms-access

I would like to send a query to R and execute R script from a command button in Microsoft Access.  Has anyone done this before and can suggest how to implement this?

Data are stored in Microsoft Access and the query is based on a button the user clicks on in Microsoft Access.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call a `Shell` command using the automated *Rscript.exe*. However first, you may need to export your query data into a format R can read such as csv or txt file. Alternatively, have R connect to database via RODBC.

In the command line call you can send parameters such as query name (for RODBC SQL statement) or csv/txt path for R to receive by concatenating the shell string with space-separated values. Then use [commandArgs()](https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) list in R to receive values.

Also, double quotes are needed if path names have any space. And if you have *Rscript* in your environmental variable, [PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them), you can use the `Rscript` command directly. Otherwise, enter full path where *Rscript.exe* resides (usually in installation bin folder). Examples commented out:

```vb
Private Sub QueryCmdButton_Click()
  DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryToExport", "C:\Path\To\CSV.csv"

  Shell "Rscript ""C:\Path\To\R\script.R""", vbNormalFocus
  ' Shell "C:\Path\To\Rscript.exe ""C:\Path\To\R\script.R""", vbNormalFocus    
  ' Shell "Rscript ""C:\Path\To\R\script.R""" & " " & qryName & " " & csvPath, vbNormalFocus

  MsgBox "Successfully processed R script!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Or a more sophisticated `Shell` call to receive a return code for error handling:

```vb
Sub RunRscript()
   Dim shell As Object
   Dim path As String
   Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
   Dim style As Integer: style = 1
   Dim errorCode As Integer

   DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryToExport", "C:\Path\To\CSV.csv"

   Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   path = "RScript ""C:\Path\To\R\script.R"""    
   errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

   Set shell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for previous annoying comments.  I couldn’t find any good documentation about this method but you seem to figure this out. I was able to get the "simple" version of your code to work with an exception for one detail please see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538004/prombelm-with-r-script-execution-from-access-2016-command-button Also, I’ve tried substituting the path into the “fancy” version of your code but I get an error message each time, not sure why? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can run R code from Microsoft Access using VBA, see https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/

To create a command button for your VBA code, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d3640d72-e91f-4d86-a52e-6d3a66888bf8/how-to-create-a-button-in-access-2010-that-runs-vba-code?forum=officesetupdeployprevious

In your R code, you can access Microsoft Access database using ODBC, see http://rprogramming.net/connect-to-ms-access-in-r/

If you have issue with 64-bit Windows and R, see [How to connect R with Access database in 64-bit Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window)