# issue with R script execution from Access 2016 command button

Tags: r, shell, ms-access, vba

I’m trying to execute R script from Access 2016 command button.  The script reads in a file and generates a plot from values inside the file. 
It works well when I run it from Windows 10 command line as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin>Rscript --vanilla H:\R\analyze.R H:\R\LCH_22.vcf
```

I would like to execute the R script from a button in Access 2016.

Here is a vba script that I'm using:

```
Dim file_path As String

file_path = "H:\R\LCH_22.vcf"

Dim RetVal
RetVal = shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe"" --vanilla ""H:\R\analyze.R"" ""H:\R\LCH_22.vcf""", vbHide)

MsgBox RetVal
```

The script executes but generates a blank plot. It has all axis and labels but all data is missing. I'm not sure why this is happening.

**Follow up**  I've replaced `vbHide` with `vbNormalFocus` and was able to generate a plot with data... yeah! However, I don't understand why substituting a variable into Shell command doesn't work.  Could someone please explain how to accomplish this correctly? I will read the file name from a form in Access and this part of the code has to be dynamic (See example of my attempt below).

```
Dim file_path
file_path = "C:\R\DNA.vcf"
Dim RetVal
RetVal = shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe"" --vanilla ""C:\R\analyze.R"" "" & file_path & """, vbNormalFocus)
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add one more pair of quotes around `file_path`:

```vb
Dim file_path As String
Dim RetVal As Integer

file_path = "C:\R\DNA.vcf"

RetVal = shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe"" --vanilla "_
               & """C:\R\analyze.R"" """ & file_path & """", vbNormalFocus)
```