# I can't figure out why my SQL statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, sqldf

I'm new to SQL and thought I'd write a simple statement to see how it works. I first connect to a database which contains a table called `LuPull`. All I'm trying to do is select all the rows from `LuPull` where the Service Number is `A107118`, but it can't find the table.

I've updated the packages, tried all combinations of the SQL statement, used

```
sqlColumns(pers, "LuPull")$COLUMN_NAME
```

which did return all the column names, so I know it sees the table, and I even used Access to generate the query and copied and pasted the Access SQL code, but all I get is this error:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: LuPull

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)
db <- "C:/Projects/MFData2005-2015.accdb"
pers <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db) 
A107 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM LuPull WHERE LuPull.[Service Number]='A107118'")
View(A107)
close(pers)
```

Comment: I am not an 'R' developer but the documentation for [sqldf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html) says it works with SQLite, H2, PostgreSQL or MySQL. On line #3 you are referencing an MS Access 20007 database. Are you sure sqldf works with MS Access?

Perhaps [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window) can help you.

Comment: I removed the sqldf and just ran it as a standalone sql statement, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sqldf for working with Access database. Use `sqlQuery`from RODBC library to select data instead.

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "C:/Projects/MFData2005-2015.accdb"
pers <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db) 
A107 <- sqlQuery(pers,"SELECT * FROM LuPull WHERE LuPull.[Service Number]='A107118'")
View(A107)
close(pers)
```

[RODBC Docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/)

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not use single quotes to delimit strings; it uses the non-standard double quotes.

Perhaps phrasing the query as valid MS Access syntax would help:

```
SELECT *
FROM LuPull
WHERE LuPull.[Service Number] = "A107118"
```

Comment: Gordon, I tried that and even added a sqlFetch statement, but I get an "unknown token LuPull" error message.

Comment: @AngustheCat . . . `LuPull` is a table name.  That makes it unlikely that is a column name -- not impossible, but unlikely.

Comment: Unless the data volume is huge, you may diagnose it with a simple `select * from LuPull`, without using filters