# Trying to work with .mdb files using R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, ms-access

I'm trying to connect with a Microsoft Access database to work with it in R using the *odbcConnect* function

```
library(RODBC)
mydb <- odbcConnectAccess("database.mdb")
```

but when I run the R script it comes with an error

```
Error: could not find function "odbcConnectAccess"
Execution halted
```

Could the error be related to trying to work with a .mdb file not using Windows? And if it is, is there another way to deal with .mdb files in ubuntu using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not straight forward. Ubuntu doesn't have MS Access ODBC drivers by default. [This answer may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113913/1671732). So the approach via RODBC package may not be fruitful.

You could try the R [Hmisc package, function mdb.get](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/Hmisc/html/mdb.get.html). This worked for me. You'll have to install the mdbtools-gmdb (via apt-get), so to have the mdb-tables command in your system.

PS: I was also stuck because my original file had a space character within its name, you should avoid that.